# Creating a Android catalog

Tags: database, catalog, app-inventor

Anyone seen an android app created with **App Inventor** that is a catalog?

I want to create app with a static DB, when a user selects a number it will display the item name, details about the item and image of that item.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this easy way if you're a beginner at programming in general and you know a bit of HTML and Javascript.

Have your database in JSON, most database management systems will export your tables in JSON format.

And here is how to insert your javascript in App inventor

http://puravidaapps.com/javascript.php

Using a javascript library will make the process even easier.

Comment: The example link demonstrates how to work with **App Inventor Classic** together with HTML/JavaScript. For **App Inventor 2**, see also [these examples](https://puravidaapps.com/tutorials.php#html)

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest to store your data in a csv file. Just add it as asset into your project and import it using the `File` component. Your catalog could be displayed using a `listpicker` component.

[Start doing the tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) to learn the basics of App Inventor. Also take a look at [How to work with Lists](http://www.imagnity.com/tutorials/app-inventor/list-blocks-on-app-inventor/) by Saj
[How to work with Lists and Lists of lists](http://www.appinventor.org/bookChapters/chapter19.pdf) (pdf) by [appinventor.org](http://www.appinventor.org/)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a list stored in an online database like firebase or a custom tinyWebDB. That way you can change the items, their prices, descriptions without having to build the app all over again. As a bonus, you could use that database to track purchases. If by static DB you mean a database on the device like tinyDB, I would still recommend using lists because they are so easy to work with.

You could have 3 paired lists. One list could be for images, one for the description, and one for the name. Then when a user picks the item number, say 3, you display item 3 of names, item 3 of descriptions, and item 3 of images.